# Create trigger after insert for user id

Tags: php, mysql

Good day to all!
I have 1 table (users) that I wish to use to update the uid field in another table (recipes).  So, when a user creates a recipe, the uid should be inserted into the *recipes* table.
This is the trigger I created, followed by the error message:

```
create trigger users_recipes 
    after insert on recipes 
    for each row  
        update recipes 
        set uid = users.uid 
        where users.uid=recipes.uid
```

> Error in INSERT into recipes (type, type2, rname, category, country, recipe, allergy, diet, path, pathvideo, posted) VALUES ('','','insert uid','','United States','blah
>   1/2 more blah','a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Nut";}','Omnivorous','','','2014-11-04') == ----->Can't update table 'recipes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

If anyone could help me understand what I did wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: seems you set wrong table name to trigger. "after insert on recipes". I think you need to specify "users" table instead "recipes"

Comment: You cannot update the table 'recipes' in that trigger because it was a modification to the 'recipes' table that triggered the trigger in the first place. Oh wait. That's what the error said. :D Reason is that updates in a trigger on the same table can result in an infinite chain of updates. Theoretically that is. In reality, the update won't trigger the insert trigger again, but MySQL apparently doesn't know that.

Comment: also maybe you need to use foreign key instead trigger ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Panoptik! This is why I'm confused, because the user is already logged in when trying to post a recipe. Sorry, just confused.  The recipes.uid field is the field I'm trying to update based off the users.uid field.

Comment: I truly appreciate your reply, GolezTrol, but.. what? (smh in state of confusion). lol